# SpringBoot how to Send response to other URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, response.redirect

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
            path = "api/api1",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> api1CallBack(@RequestBody String requestBody, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, URISyntaxException {
       String response="{SOME_JSON}";
        URI callbackURL = new URI("http://otherAPIEnv/api2");
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setLocation(callbackURL);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(response,httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I tried the above code, but when I hit the api1 through my curl I get the response on the same machine, but I want the response to be redirected to api2 at otherAPIEnv machine.

Could someone please suggest how to achieve this kind of request and response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you send a request to a URL it should respond to the same otherwise client will be in waiting for it until it times out.

So, the approach should be different in this scenario.

First, in your main rest API you have to send a response code to release the client.

Then, in the API method you have to call another method asynchronously which calls api2 and performs the desired operation.

Here is a simple example.

```
@Autowired
API2Caller api2Caller;

@RequestMapping(
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
        path = "api/api1",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE
)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void api1CallBack(@RequestBody String requestBody, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, URISyntaxException {
    api2Caller.callApi2(requestBody);
}
```

and the APICaller should look like following

```
@Component
public class API2Caller {

    @Async
    public SomeResultPojo callApi2() {
        // use RestTemplate to call the api2 
        return restTemplate.postForObject("http://otherAPIEnv/api2", request, SomeResultPojo.class);
    }
}
```

But you can choose your most comfortable way to perform asynchronous operation.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a good approach, but is there any better approach provided specially for this type of case in SpringBoot?

Comment: If someone calls api1 and api1 does not responds it but it sends response to api2 violates the basic principal of request / response. Every request must have a response and secondly you cannot send a response without request (case of api2).in http protocol. 

I have similar situation in many of my microservice api and we did the same, but as i said in my answer the approach of calling the api2 can be different and depends upon your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Look like a job for `redirect`.

```
String redirectMe() {
    return "redirect:http://otherAPIEnv/api2"
}
```

As for the curl. You have `POST` mapping of the method so be sure to try it with `curl -X POST...` or change it to `GET`.

Comment: so you mean I should use URI callbackURL = new URI("redirect: http ://otherAPIEnv/api2"); instead of URI callbackURL = new URI(" http ://otherAPIEnv/api2");

Comment: @ps-aux "redirect: <some uri>" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This the more modular and more generic way to do such kind of things:

```
public @ResponseBody ClientResponse updateDocStatus(MyRequest myRequest) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = new ClientResponse(CTConstants.FAILURE);
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = prepareHeaders();
        ClientRequest request = prepareRequestData(myRequest);
        logger.info("cpa request is " + new Gson().toJson(request));
        HttpEntity<ClientRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<ClientRequest>(request, headers);
        String uri = cpaBaseUrl + updateDocUrl ;    
        ClientResponse serviceResponse = Utilities.sendHTTPRequest(uri, entity);
        clientResponse = serviceResponse;
        if (serviceResponse != null) {
            if (CTConstants.SUCCESS.equalsIgnoreCase(serviceResponse.getStatus())) {
                clientResponse.setStatus(CTConstants.SUCCESS);
                clientResponse.setMessage(" update success.");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("exception occurred ", e);
        clientResponse.setStatus(CTConstants.ERROR);
        clientResponse.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
    return clientResponse;
}



    public static ClientResponse sendHTTPRequest(String uri, HttpEntity<ClientRequest> entity) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
        rf.setReadTimeout(CTConstants.SERVICE_TIMEOUT);
        rf.setConnectTimeout(CTConstants.SERVICE_TIMEOUT);

        ParameterizedTypeReference<ClientResponse> ptr = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ClientResponse>() {
        };
        ResponseEntity<ClientResponse> postForObject = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, ptr);
        return postForObject.getBody();

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `redirect` and modify the return type of your method

```
public String api1CallBack(@RequestBody String requestBody, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
       return "redirect:http://otherAPIEnv/api2";
}
```

Comment: Actually the api2 url is a post url on which we have to post some data (the value of json in response variable)